# App icons in Software Center not appearing in all places

Tags: software-center, icons

Initially, the icons in Software Center (gnome-software, Ubuntu 21.10) were not there and only appeared as I selected a category and waited for them -- apparently they were being downloaded?  (NOTE: I am using 'Yaru-dark' theme but I tried switching to 'Yaru' -- the default -- and it still exhibited the behavior.)

But even after they appear, the icon displayed when going to view an app or that would be displayed in the scrolling "featured" list at the top, is missing and only appears as a read square with a "not" symbol.

[image: Featured list]
[image: Category view]
[image: App details]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Is this snap store or gnome software?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Ubuntu 21.10; gnome-software. I updated the OP.